# Split a list of two tuples based on the items in the second dimension

Tags: python, dictionary, classification

There is a list called *a* with two dimensions. `a[0]` is a tuple of 1000 images, and `a[1]` is the tuple of their labels. I am trying to run the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
images = defaultdict(list)  
for image, label in a:
    images[label].append(image)

for k,v in images.iteritems():
    print('Label {} has {} images'.format(k, len(v)))
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
for image, label in a:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: You can use `zip`: `for image, label in zip(*a): ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the first loop to:

```
for image, label in zip(*a):
```

This will combine corresponding pairs from `a[0]` and `a[1]` so that you can loop through them.

Comment: Thank you. It works without error, but wondering after using zip command, it shows the result, and then goes to sleep and works very slow. I have to exit Spyder and again run.

Comment: Is there more code after the second loop?  It may not be in the code you posted.

Comment: no, usually I have this problem whenever I am using zip command.

Comment: I don't think it's very likely that `zip` is the cause of the problem, unless your lists are very large and it's using excessive amounts of memory (I think this would only be a problem in Python 2 though, since in Python 3 `zip` returns an iterator).